# open ip addresses for redshift and data factory

Tags: azure, amazon-redshift, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to connect an instance of Azure's Data Factory to Amazon Redshift. I have all the connection details, but the issue is that I need to open the IP address of the Redshift database for it to work. I know this because if I open all IP addresses, I can connect fine. Without them being open though, I get a connection timeout.

For security reasons, I can't leave all IP addresses open. I need to figure out the one Data Factory is operating on, and just open that.

The consensus seems to be, however, that Data Factory does not operate on a static IP address.

Comment: Have you looked at the prerequisites for copying from Redshift to either on-premise or Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-redshift#prerequisites. If on-premise - integration runtime IP address will be used, else it will be Aure IP Address range.

Comment: I used the ranges, but was wondering if it could be narrowed further. I guess the answer is no?

Comment: Range is the only way to setup this and much better than opening database to all IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also setup a selfhosted IR for your redshift. Reference that IR in your redshift linked service. Then you only need open IP address of the machine hosting that selfhosted IR.
Make sure your source and sink reference the same selfhosted IR if sink is also on premises.